# MKMapView setCenterCoordinate:animated does not centred properly

Tags: ios, mkmapview

I have a problem:
MKMapView setCenterCoordinate:animated does not centred properly sometimes (not regulary). I used simple code:

```
[self.mapView setCenterCoordinate:self.currentUserCoordinate animated:NO];
```

I noted that when I use `animated:YES`, it works good.

[image: image not in center]

How to fix it? Thank you!